# Using react-select with react server side rendering make problems

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-hooks, server-side-rendering, react-select

I have problems with react-select library which i use with server side rendering of react, i have tried different versions of react-select. So, the problem is when i am using client side rendering, everything is working fine but when i switch to server side rendering i got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'registered' of null
at 2.99e944f3.chunk.js:2:55545"

The things that i tried to resolve the error are:

1. Experimenting with the library(the different props that i add to it)
2. trying different version of the library

One addition to this is that i use react with typescript

How i use Select

````
<Select         
              className="basic-single"
              onChange={(e) => {field.onChange(e); onChangeHandler(e) }}
              value={value}enter code here
              styles={customStyles}
              classNamePrefix="react-select"
              isDisabled={isDisabled}></Select>```
````